# Is it possible to synchronize lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, synchronization

For instance, if I have a list of words:

```
Words = ['A', 'list', 'of', 'words']
```

and want a second list to reference the lengths of those words, how could I achieve this? I'm aware that I could do something like:

```
Lengths = map(lambda w: len(w), Words)
[1, 4, 2, 5]
```

but I would have to continually call that function every time Words is altered.

Comment: Maybe a class would allow you to do that.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm a Python novice. :p

Comment: I think he's trying to say you'd need to use a subclass of `list` so you could update `Lengths` automatically when you changed `Words`. If your question is "is there is a built-in way of doing this" the answer is no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a class:

```
class mywords:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.words = a
        self.length = map(lambda w: len(w), a)
    def append(self, string):
        self.words.append(string)
        self.length.append(len(string))


a = mywords(['A', 'list', 'of', 'words'])

a.append("this")
print a.words
print a.length
```

It's the first time I use a class, so there might be a better way. However this seems to work well. You would need to define other methods for other operations such as insert, remove, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In your suggestion a list comprehension would be nicer to look at and faster:

```
[len(word) for word in words]
```

You could use a dict comprehension like so:

```
{word: len(word) for word in words}
```

But really, there is no advantage in that over just generating the length of the word when you need it. If you desperately need it to automatically update, I'd suggest the best option is just to write your own class to manage it.

Comment: It's a bit of a convenience in the context I'm working in - word lengths is just a placeholder for what I'm trying to do with the synced lists. If it's not possible, it isn't a big deal, but like I said, it would help.